# Weird error when trying to create new angular app

Tags: angular, npm-install

I am getting this error when I am trying to create anew angular app with

```
ng new frontend
```

This is the error I get

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dSize":36422127},"eng'
```

So I referred npm git issues but I couldn't find a solution , and they suggested it could be  network problem and some suggested reinstalling or updating nodejs, npm, and angular cli. I did update everything by reinstalling all the required software but when I tried to run the following -

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

I still get the same error. Please suggest what I need to do to  create a new ng app with angular 2+( 4, 5, 6).

**UPDATE**
This is where it fails according to log - I tried it with a lower version of node too

```
451 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@>=2.6.2 <2.10 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dSize":36422127},"eng'
452 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dSize":36422127},"eng'
452 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
452 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
452 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
452 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
452 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
453 verbose cwd D:\
454 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
455 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ganesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
456 verbose node v8.9.4
457 verbose npm  v5.6.0
```

**Update 2**
Since I found that the error existed with installing Typescript I tried to directly install Typescript using

```
 npm i -g typescript
```

and I found that it is trying to access a file at

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
```

and also I found that there is only one such location in the json where the error occurs. Here is the new log: -

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Ganesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'typescript' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose npm-session 51a5c57f485d99fd
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 31ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dSize":36422127},"eng'
9 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dSize":36422127},"eng'
9 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
9 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
9 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
9 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
9 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
10 verbose cwd D:\
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
12 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ganesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "typescript"
13 verbose node v8.9.4
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dSize":36422127},"eng'
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

But now what do I do ? Please help me with next steps.

Comment: what is your current version of node and npm (npm -v) (node-v). Did you try to clean npm cache (npm cache clean --force) !warning - cache clean removes cache from npm so your next installations will be slower.

Comment: @Drag13 Yes I cleaned the cache and reinstalled node and npm, but when I try to install angular Cli I am getting the JSON parse error.

Comment: So I assume you got latest node and npm, right? Try to install not latest cli but specific like 6.1.4

Comment: @Drag13 
    npm version 6.4.1-next.0
    node version v8.11.1
Will uninstall and try with other versions.

Comment: I mean specific version of cli, and stable version of npm

Comment: @Drag13 I referred this https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ and installed npm 5.6.0 for node 8.11.1 but I still am not able to install @angular/cli

Comment: I found this in the error log - silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@>=2.6.2 <2.10 Unexpected

Comment: Sounds like a bug in third party dependencie. Could you try to drammatically downgrade cli version?

Comment: @Drag13 Please refer my update.

Comment: Please refer Update 2 as it is the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the answer to my problem and so I tried using a new user account in Windows 10. And it worked. For now, this helped me. I still am so uncomfortable with such issues in Windows.

Comment: This is extremely wired, but thanks for sharing. Do you mind about creating new bug report?

Comment: @Drag13 I did report an issue because I wasn't sure whether it was a bug with npm, and since it got solved the moment I logged in to another account I think it was a windows problem. However, I will create a bug report just in case it could help somebody. Thanks for cooperation.